# logout facebook in MVC asp.net graph api

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api

I'm having trouble with the logout Facebook.

I have project MVC ASP.NET with adding OWIN. I use the application to log into my app in FB, getting the access token.
When I get information, I was logout with Facebook. Then I was log in to another account to Facebook and make things.

In my app is used a graph FB API. I sent and post a request.

I know, that I log out with example process:

https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=mypage&access_token=mytoken

but I don't know to make to not go to next page in the browser.

In the other way, I log out using a javascript.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout
This method is good when I had no cookie in the browser. I log in and log out. So.. When I try to log in again, it's good, but I don't logout

Comment: _“but I don't konw to make to not go to next page in browser”_ - why would you want that? Let the user return to your page, then the next person can click your login button there again.

Comment: User log in to press the button. When user log I take access token, after I want to log out the user. I want automatic log out the user.

Comment: Well then redirect to the logout URL, after you fetched the access token ...

Comment: It woks. Thanks.

Now I have next trouble. The user login to fb, fb app please a perssmion, but the user dosn't agree to requests. So... The user is login to FB, but my program see the user is not login. Then I don't logout the user becuse I don't have a its access token.

Comment: Well in such a case you have to make the user logout manually, by going to facebook.com directly. It is not possible to log a user out without a valid access token (because if it was, then _every_ website that you visit could log you out of Facebook, and that obviously must not be possible.) // What is the overall purpose of what you are building here? You got to be careful with multiple users logging in on the same device, from the same IP, in a short amount of time - this can easily trigger Facebook security algorithms.